# how to change and load a config file which depends on the url param in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

my question is i have two config files and i would like to change the config file on pageload which depends on the url param ?

for now i have done someting like this :

config-loader.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfigLoaderService {     
constructor(private injector: Injector, private http?: HttpClient) { }
    
      public get router(): Router {
        return this.injector.get(Router);
     }
    
      url : string;
      link : string;
      initialize() {
        this.url = this.router.url;
        if (this.url == "/demo")
        {
          this.link = 'assets/demoConfig.json'
        }
        else {
          this.link = 'assets/config.json'
        }
        return this.http.get<ModeActivation>(this.link)
          .pipe(tap((response: ModeActivation) => {
```

app.module.ts

```
  providers: [DemandeClass,
    ConfigLoaderService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      deps: [
        ConfigLoaderService
      ],
      multi: true,
      useFactory: PreloadFactory
    }
  ],
```

with this i am not getting an error but the

> this.router.url

is always  "/" even if i enter

> localhost:4200/demo

so it enter in my second condition! What am i doing wrong ? anyone pls

Comment: I reproduced your problem.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ruaypv

Comment: @StPaulis  thanks for reproducing it but any solutions ?

Comment: Unfortunately no... 

It would be better If you could tell us what exactly are you trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you are accessing the router, the app is still initialising and the router has not navigated internally to your url.

As a proof, you can check the value of `this.router.navigated` in your config service, which will be false (and true after one navigation has been completed, see the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#properties))

**Solution**

Instead of using the router, you can use `window.location.pathname`

```
initialize() {
    this.url = window.location.pathname;// instead of this.router.url;
    console.log("Has router navigated?", this.router.navigated) //will be false
    console.log('current url', this.url); //correct url
```

Here is a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-h3jwhx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the config in the route data?

```
{
                path: 'path',
                component: Component,
                data: myConfigForThsiRoute,
            },
```